# Strange resoult of division in c

Tags: c, division

My program in c gives me strange output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

int a,b;
float c;

printf("Input values of  a i b: \n");

scanf("%f%f",&a,&b);
c =a*(a+b)/(float)((a+b)*(a+b));
printf("Resoult of expression is: %f\n", c);



}
```

Resault is always like: -1.#IND00

Why does it happends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading in `int` values using the `%f` formatter flag, which is meant for `float`.  `a` and `b` are of type `int`, so you want to use `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
  scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
```

instead of

```
   scanf("%f%f",&a,&b);
```

because `%f` is used to represent float type and `%d` is for integers.Since a and b are integers,so you must use `%d`.